# Matching vector elements to different levels in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I have a data frame containing participants' responses to a set of questions which looks like this:

```
      RT Response Familiarity         ID  PP
1 116.75        5         Yes    batBall pp1
2  78.40       47          No    lilyPad pp1
3  17.26        8          No  farmSheep pp1
4  37.67        0         Yes   dirtHole pp1
5  24.56        5         Yes widgetTime pp1
6   8.16   second         Yes  racePlace pp1
```

`ID` refers to the individual question and `Response` is the participant's response. Every question has two possible answers: a `Correct` answer and an `Intuitive` answer. I created two vectors: one vector containing strings of all possible Correct answers, and one vector containing strings of all possible intuitive answers. The goal is to create these two extra columns which contain `TRUE` or `FALSE` if the `Response` matches any of the elements in the `Correct` and `Intuitive` vectors:

```
Answers=c("5","47","8","0","5","second")
Intuitive=c("10","24","7","27","100","first")

CRTData$Intuitive=ifelse(CRTData$Response %in% Intuitive,TRUE,FALSE)
CRTData$Correct=ifelse(CRTData$Response %in% Answers,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Bear in mind that is a truncated version of the vectors - in reality, the vectors will also include variations of answers depending on the question (e.g. `5`, `five`, `0.05`). The above code works with no problem (in this case, `pp1` scored all questions correctly):

```
      RT Response Familiarity         ID  PP Intuitive Correct
1 116.75        5         Yes    batBall pp1     FALSE    TRUE
2  78.40       47          No    lilyPad pp1     FALSE    TRUE
3  17.26        8          No  farmSheep pp1     FALSE    TRUE
4  37.67        0         Yes   dirtHole pp1     FALSE    TRUE
5  24.56        5         Yes widgetTime pp1     FALSE    TRUE
6   8.16   second         Yes  racePlace pp1     FALSE    TRUE
```

The problem arises when a participant inputs a totally incorrect answer, but this answer happens to be part of the two vectors above. For example, if a participant responds to `lilyPad` (which only has two answer variants: `24` or `47`) with `7` , the `Intuitive` column is marked as `TRUE` when it should be `FALSE` for `lilyPad`. It is being marked as `TRUE` because `7` *is* in the `Intuitive` vector, but it is the intuitive response for the `farmSheep` question:

```
        RT Response Familiarity         ID   PP Intuitive Correct
1928 10.75   second         Yes  racePlace pp42     FALSE    TRUE
1929  7.57        0          No   dirtHole pp42     FALSE    TRUE
1930 54.47        7          No  farmSheep pp42      TRUE   FALSE
1931 43.33      100          No widgetTime pp42      TRUE   FALSE
1932 14.00       10          No    batBall pp42      TRUE   FALSE
1933 39.56        7          No    lilyPad pp42      TRUE   FALSE
1934  9.68    emily          No  emilyName pp42     FALSE    TRUE
```

Now, the only solution I have in mind would be to create a list of 14 vectors (2 for each question ID - a correct and intuitive, e.g. `lilyPadIntuitive`, `lilyPadCorrect`), and then match the `Response` of each `ID` to the accordingly to avoid errors like the case of `pp42`. I would then imagine a nested `for` loop might be the solution but I think this makes the answer a bit messy and convoluted.

If anyone happens to know a simpler solution to this problem, I would highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using package `dplyr`.

I would suggest a small "redesign" in your data storage. First of all we have a data.frame

```r
> df  # in your case: CRTData
# A tibble: 9 x 6
     RT Response    Familiarity ID         PP   
  <dbl> <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      <chr>
1 117.   5           Yes         batBall    pp1  
2  78.4  47          No          lilyPad    pp1  
3  17.3  8           No          farmSheep  pp1  
4  37.7  0           Yes         dirtHole   pp1  
5  24.6  5           Yes         widgetTime pp1  
6   8.16 second      Yes         racePlace  pp1  
7   9.16 7           Yes         lilyPad    pp3  
8  10.2  fourtyseven Yes         lilyPad    pp4  
9   9.16 7           Yes         farmSheep  pp3
```

that contains your participants' responses. I suggest, that `PP` is a unique ID per participant and `ID` is used to distinguish the questions.

Now we have two vectors of possible answers

```
Answers   <- c("5","47","8","0","5","second")
Intuitive <- c("10","24","7","27","100","first")
```

I suppose, they are in the same order as the questions, e.g. question `batBall` corresponds to answer "5" and intuitive "10", `lilyPad` to "47" and "24".

Let's store them in another data.frame

```
> df2  # there are better names
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  ID         Answers     Intuitive 
  <chr>      <chr>       <chr>     
1 batBall    5           10        
2 lilyPad    47          24        
3 farmSheep  8           7         
4 dirtHole   0           27        
5 widgetTime 5           100       
6 racePlace  second      first     
7 lilyPad    fourtyseven twentyfour
```

I added a line with possible variations for question `lilyPad`.

```
df %>% 
  left_join(df2, by="ID") %>%
  group_by(ID, PP) %>%
  mutate(Answers=any(Response==Answers),
         Intuitive=any(Response==Intuitive)) %>%
  distinct()
```

This yields

```r
# A tibble: 9 x 7
# Groups:   ID, PP [9]
      RT Response    Familiarity ID         PP    Answers Intuitive
   <dbl> <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      <chr> <lgl>   <lgl>    
1 117.   5           Yes         batBall    pp1   TRUE    FALSE    
2  78.4  47          No          lilyPad    pp1   TRUE    FALSE    
3  17.3  8           No          farmSheep  pp1   TRUE    FALSE    
4  37.7  0           Yes         dirtHole   pp1   TRUE    FALSE    
5  24.6  5           Yes         widgetTime pp1   TRUE    FALSE    
6   8.16 second      Yes         racePlace  pp1   TRUE    FALSE    
7   9.16 7           Yes         lilyPad    pp3   FALSE   FALSE    
8  10.2  fourtyseven Yes         lilyPad    pp4   TRUE    FALSE    
9   9.16 7           Yes         farmSheep  pp3   FALSE   TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves the issue perfectly. There are many answer variations so I may end up pre-building the second dataframe in Excel as a .csv file if it gets a bit complicated or messy. One warning I ran into with this code was: `Column ID joining character vector and factor, coercing into character vector`. I assume that the `ID` column in both data frames should be classified as a factor? Would that make a difference?

Comment: I think in your case that won't make any difference. The decision between a character and a factor depends on the actual task.